# Time stamp in spanish?

Tags: php, datetime, date, programming-languages, timestamp

I'm creating a time stamp which I would like to be in Spanish.

The code I have:

```
 $day = (date("D")); // day in number
 switch($day) {
  case "1": $m = "lunes"; break;
  case "2": $m = "martes"; break;
  case "3": $m = "miércoles"; break;
  case "4": $m = "jueves"; break;
  case "5": $m = "viernes"; break;
  case "6": $m = "sábago"; break;
  case "7": $m = "domingo"; break;
    default: "";
 }
 echo $m;
```

But for some reason it echo's out nothing for 'm'. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a typo or are you missing `switch` before `($day)`?

Comment: D returns the 3 letter name, not number.

Comment: @Corbin so would i implement that by case "mon": $m="lunes";

Comment: date supports your locale. Properly configured, and using the right format code, would render the whole code unnecessary. http://php.net/date

Comment: The good answer is hakre's. Just change the locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make your code more safe:

```
default: throw new Exception(sprintf('Unexpected value: "%s"', $day));
```

this will point you with the nose to your error. now or in the future (e.g. when the locale changes).

Comment: Sorry don't have alot of knowledge here, could you explain how it works a little, Thanks.

Comment: every time it has a value you didn't create a case for, default jumps in and throws an exception. That will halt your script and give you a message telling you what went wrong. You then can quickly change your code so that it works again.